# Partitioning of an array in to

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Given an array of positive integers {a1, a2, ..., an} you are required to partition the array into k blocks/partitions such that the maximum of sums of integers in each partition is the minimum it can be. Restriction: you cannot alter the turn in which the numbers appear (example: if you have {2, 5, 80, 1, 200, 80, 8000, 90} one partition CANNOT be the {2, 80, 1, 90}).  I need the output partition-values and the maximum sum of the partition.  Some kind of Knuth's algorithm or anything else? Any sugggestion? I have no idea... 
So, for example:

{11, 16, 5, 5, 12, 10} n (n=3)

The best partitioning according to the problem is:

[(11), (16, 5, 5), (12, 10)]

Comment: SORRY... {11, 16, 5, 5, 12, 10} k (K = 3)

Comment: Your asking for *some kind of Knuth's algorithm* has left me perplexed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for help with homework in Stackoverflow. But please notice that you must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but rather a math/algorithm question.

Comment: I've changed the tags

Comment: @Escualo: As I understand Knuth's algorithm correct, it will give me all combinations. Also combinations, which cannot be f.e. : [(11, 10), (16, 5) , (12, 5)]: the sequence is FIX. I'm trying to minimize the calculations. I thought about an matrix (n)(k)..., but how to solve it?

Comment: @user5115933 Knuth has tens of thousands of pages written about algorithms, **what algorithm are you talking about?**

Comment: @Escualo: as I asked above: I need all combinations of a FIXED array or list. What algorithm would be the best? :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can't change the order of the numbers in the array, my suggestion of the solution is:

1. Binary search on the maximum sum
2. Given the current maximum sum, use greedy algorithm to see if `k` blocks are enough to cover the whole array.

The algorithm looks like:

```
l=0
r=sum(A)
while l<=r:
  mid=(l+r)/2;
  if greedy(mid):
    r=mid-1
  else:
    l=mid+1
```

The final maximum sum will be `l`, and you can use it to construct the partition using greedy.

And the function `greedy` will look like:

```
def greedy(s):
  now_k=0
  now_sum=0
  for i in A:
    now_sum+=i
    if now_sum>s:
      now_sum=0
      now_k++
  if nowsum > 0:
    now_k++
  return now_k<=k
```